# onhover add effects to all unselected bar in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, opacity

My requirement is to turn out other column bar graph in highcharts to dim color when we hover over one. I looked for this on community but found no specific answer. my code is as below:

```
                        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

                        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ios, 'jquery-1.9.1.js')}"/>

                        <script>
                            var lowerIndex;
                            var upperIndex;
                            if({!maxBarVisible}==0)
                            {
                                lowerIndex = 0;
                                upperIndex = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lowerIndex = {!maxBarVisible} - ({!maxBarVisible}-1);
                                upperIndex = {!maxBarVisible};
                            }
                            $(function () {
                                var chart;
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                                        chart: {
                                            renderTo: 'container',
                                            type: 'column',
                                            marginRight: 50,
                                            marginBottom: 30
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                                text:''
                                          },  
                                        credits: {
                                            enabled: false
                                          },
                                        legend: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        },
                                        scrollbar:{
                                          enabled:{!showSlider}
                                        },

                                        xAxis: {
                                          min:lowerIndex,
                                          max:upperIndex,
                                            categories: [{!x_axisMonths}]
                                        },
                                        yAxis: {
                                            min: 0,
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'MRR($)'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        colors: [
                                           'rgb(24, 150, 212)', 
                                           'rgb(116, 187, 59)', 

                                        ],
                                        tooltip: {
                                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                                            shared: true,
                                            useHTML: true,
                                           tip: 'bottomLeft'

                                        },
                                        series: [{!y_axisData}]
                                    });
                                });

                            });
                        </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: avoid lot of blank space in indentation.. it becomes difficult to read that way

Comment: Check [hover state](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.states.hover) for column.

Comment: I got it resolved. Please let me know if any one requires the same.

Comment: You should specify how you managed to solve your problem, in order to help future users who come across the same (or very alike) problem.